# how to create reminder email for yearly recurring events in SharePoint 2013 calendar?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-calendar

I need to create a calendar in SharePoint for my company which shows all the public holidays of 7 countries.

And a reminder email must be sent out automatically to all the colleagues 3-4 days before the each public holiday. This will be repeating for every year. Some of the public holidays date might get changed for each year(exp for Eid).

I've tried Mr.Google to search for a possible solution but couldn't find. I'm quite new for SharePoint as well.

Please assist me on this.

Comment: You can use workflow

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that this need to be done using workflow. But i'm not sure how to setup. Is there any step by step guidance for this? Hope someone can help..

Comment: you know how to create workflows?

Comment: I have SharePoint designer 2013.. I've created workflow for my approval forms.. But never done for reminder workflows.. Hope you can guide through

Comment: Is timer job an option? If number of items are large wf will strain your system and timer job would be a better solution.

Comment: what is timer job? I have a data of public holidays for seven countries..

Comment: Lets go with Workflow then :D, I'll post a solution

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up a workflow that sends an email using retention policies.

Using SharePoint Designer you will be able to create a simple email (make sure the workflow is 2010). You will need to set an additional date field that will contain the date 3-4 days prior to the event (you will have to add an extra date column). You can set this field manually for each date or set it automatically using an additional workflow.

Use the retention policies and settings to run the reminder workflow (has to be a 2010 workflow) 1 year after the date in a date field (e.g. 1 year after the priorToHoliday) and then set how often the workflow should recur (i.e. once a year).

[See this linked answer for a more in depth on how to set up and use retention settings](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/164457/39441)

Answer (score 0):

You can use workflows but there would be some limitations which are in the end.

Steps:

1. Create a calculated Column "Remind Date" with formula : `=[Start Time]-4`
2. Create a SharePoint list workflow on calendar list with the following steps

[image]

1. Here in these users you can email ID and the email content

**Limitations:**

1. Only one reminder can be set for one event.
2. More workflow can be added to allow more reminders.
3. The workflow will not stop when user modify the event. User need to delete the event and create new event with new remind time.
4. The start time is default 8 am if the event is a all day event.