# Workflow To Send Multiple Calendar Reminders

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-calendar

all,

I'm trying to build a workflow that sends reminders to the creator of a SharePoint calendar entry 2 weeks before the event, 3 days before, the day of, and the day after.

I created date variables for each reminder and came up with the following. If someone would please look over the workflow and let me know if I'm on the right track, I would appreciate it greatly

[image]

Comment: Are these meant to be run as 4 separate workflows or as one workflow?

Comment: Hi, Roland.  I want this is as a single workflow with four steps, but this is where my limited workflow experience comes in and I'm not sure if I wrote it correctly.  

What it boils down to is I need to have emails fire at specific intervals for each calendar event added.  I can write a single email workflow to send one reminder, but I'm not sure if this is how I should write a multiple email reminder workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Run this as a single workflow you will need to change the the Stop Workflow lines and replace them with Pause until X. Stop Workflow will stop the workflow from running until it is triggered again (i.e run workflow on modification).
If you are looking to simply pause and log a message then you should write it as:

Log *your message*

Pause until *Your Date*

Alternatively you could look into using retention settings to run the (4)workflows based on the date requirements which in my opinion is much cleaner, especially if you need to change the dates that these workflows run at. If the emails are generic enough you could even just have 1-2 micro workflows.

Here is a great answer from another question on how to do so (Disclaimer I have the accepted answer however the linked answer is not mine).
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/164457/39441

Comment: Thank you, Roland.  I appreciate your time and information on this.